# text area does not sense when next line is being used

Tags: html

i am working on a project , where i am required to save the input of the user as the user hits save .

```
<form name="input" action="updater.php" method="get"><label>
<textarea  name="addr" cols="62" rows="29">
Your Message will be     displayed here . </textarea>
```

issue is, i can save the input of the user. but if user hits 'Enter' text area does not sense it , i-e if i enter

```
Hello 
world
```

it saves

```
Hello World
```

instead it should be

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Neither does SO from the looks of it ;)

Comment: @Niklas - It's because SO uses a textarea, hence my joke lol. I've edited the question.

Comment: @faizi 'It saves'?? How are you getting the data?

Comment: i mean , GET in the link

Answer (score 1):

In various operating systems different characters are used to represent a new line. Sometimes it is \r, sometimes \n or sometimes both \r\n.

You need to make sure you are preserving line breaks when the user saves their submitted form, and account for the fact that any combination of the above might be sent.

In addition, be sure you are correctly returning these when you view what was saved. For example in the textarea it is stored as \r\n. **To display a new line in HTML, you must use `<br />`.**

This is easily done in PHP using `nl2br();`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your r using php to retrieve nd display the stored string, you can display it correctly by using the `nl2br` function to display the string. Please do well to close all html tags next time.

Answer (score 0):

When a user hits Enter, a system-dependent control character is inserted into `value` property of the the `textarea` element node. If the `textarea` is part of a form and the form is submitted, those conrol characters are canonicalized to CR LF (Carriage Return, LineFeed) pairs.

The rest depends on the client-side or server-side code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

make use of `encodeURIComponent` while storing and `decodeURIComponent` after retrieval from databse.
check out fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/ztB7Q/

for more details,check out this **[Encoding and decoding using JavaScript and PHP](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/#section_0)**, hope you will get your answer here.